Shared element transition with CameraX + Compose
Does anyone know how to achieve the same transition for camera openning with Compose as it's done in Telegram? I have two ideas, but none is succcessful yet:

Using Shared element transition - but I really don't know how to achieve this without recreating Camera instance (it always creates another one on transition)
Just expand the camera item to fullscreen size. But I don't know how to do this inside the LazyGrid

So the main question is How to expand an item from LazyGrid that has TextureView  to fullscreen size without reopenning the camera.
